# Ninja Framework mailProvider.get() gives a Null pointer exception

Tags: nullpointerexception, ninjaframework

I did everything according to instructions.

application.conf contains:

```
smtp.host=smtp.gmail.com
smtp.port=465
smtp.ssl=true
smtp.user=myemail@gmail.com
smtp.password=xxxxxx
smtp.debug=false
```

The code contains

```
    package controllers;


import ninja.postoffice.Mail;
import ninja.postoffice.Postoffice;
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.google.inject.Provider;

public class MailController {

    @Inject
    Provider<Mail> mailProvider;

    @Inject
    Postoffice postoffice;

    public void sendMail(String to) {
        try {
        Mail mail = mailProvider.get();
......
```

It fails at mailProvider.get() giving the java.lang.NullPointerException

What am I missing ??

EDIT, THE STACK TRACE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at controllers.MailController.sendMail(MailController.java:19)
        at controllers.RegisterResendController.confirmation(RegisterResendController.java:37)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at ninja.params.ControllerMethodInvoker.invoke(ControllerMethodInvoker.java:57)
        at ninja.FilterChainEnd.next(FilterChainEnd.java:49)
        at ninja.NinjaDefault.onRouteRequest(NinjaDefault.java:102)
        at ninja.servlet.NinjaServletDispatcher.service(NinjaServletDispatcher.java:86)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doServiceImpl(ServletDefinition.java:287)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.doService(ServletDefinition.java:277)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ServletDefinition.service(ServletDefinition.java:182)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedServletPipeline.service(ManagedServletPipeline.java:91)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.FilterChainInvocation.doFilter(FilterChainInvocation.java:85)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:119)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$1.call(GuiceFilter.java:133)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$1.call(GuiceFilter.java:130)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter$Context.call(GuiceFilter.java:203)
        at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:130)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Please provide the stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: @nullpointer please see the edited post for a stack-trace

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @jipr311 No it is not, please show some respect. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow your RegisterResendController must get an instance of MailController. I suspect that instance of MailController is not injected into RegisterSendController. And therefore lacking any instances provided by Guice. Make sure you don't create instances of your class on your own (via 'new MailController' and such).

Please also paste line numbers and RegisterSendController if you want to get more feedback.

Comment: That is probably what the case is, I will let you know as soon as I test it.